# change-merged gerrit hook

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm trying to make alternative to **post-receive** hook, but may be i something did wrong.
Does this hook work with push commit to master branch (without /for/ control) through gerrit (i have permission to do push commits)? Official doc doesn't give explanation what "merge" request like.

I placed change-merged script to gerrit/hook/ dir (gerrit is the directory with "bin", "plugins" and other gerrit places) , is it right too?

Comment: Ok, i found out that post-receive hook emitted only when merge approved through web interface. When commit overcoming web interface (push access) it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The `hooks` folder within the gerrit site folder (also containing `bin`, `plugins`, `git`, etc) is the correct place to put hook files.

However, `post-receive` is a git hook, not a Gerrit hook, and Gerrit will not invoke it.

Gerrit will invoke `change-merged` and `ref-updated` hooks when a change is merged from the UI, but only `ref-updated` if a change is directly pushed bypassing the review.

See the [Gerrit hooks documentation](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/config-hooks.html) for more information.

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to turn running Gerrit hooks on or off? (e.g. we turned it off somewhere, maybe). None of these server side hooks run for me.

Comment: Might it be that things inside `${site_path}/git/your_project.git/hooks/` are *never* run? But only those in `${site_path}/hooks/` (a directory which you need to create yourself). `${site_path}/logs/error_log` seems to mutter a bit about the latter path.